# Using two pipes to communicate between parent process and child process

Tags: c, pipe, fork, wait

#### Problem

I only get this in the terminal output. I believe the program is getting stuck at the `fork()` call but I don't know exactly why.

The name of the program is q9:

```
prompt>$ ./q9 inputString
Parent: writing to pipe 'inputString'
```

#### Task

- read input from terminal into the parent-to-child pipe.
- fork() to create a child process.
- read input from parent-to-child pipe.
- concatenate some other string to that string read in from the pipe.
- write the newly concatenated string to the child-to-parent pipe.
- in the parent, read from the child-to-parent pipe and print the output read from the pipe to the terminal.

#### Attempts

I have tried fixing this by:

- attempting to close pipes in different places. I thought I may have missed something or left something open, but I don't think so.
- placing a wait() in the parent because perhaps it wasn't letting the child run completely
- attempted to print the output of the concatenated string just in case it was that messing up the prints.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // parent RUN
    if(argc == 1) {
        printf("usage: q9 <string>\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // create two way pipes
    int parent_fds[2], child_fds[2];

    // create strings to save too
    char fromParent[100];
    char fromChild[100];

    // read:[0] - write:[1]
    if (pipe(parent_fds) != 0 && pipe(child_fds) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipes failed!\n");
    }

    // close unused pipe end by parent
    close(parent_fds[0]);
    close(child_fds[1]);
    close(child_fds[0]);

    // write from terminal to parent pipe FOR child to read
    printf("Parent: writing to pipe '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    write(parent_fds[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    close(parent_fds[1]);

    // fork() child process
    int child = fork();

    // NEVER GETS PASSED HERE :(

    if (child < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed!");
        exit(1);
    } else if (child == 0) {
        printf("I reached the child :)");
        // close unwanted pipe ends by child
        close(child_fds[0]);
        close(parent_fds[1]);

        // read from parent pipe
        int n = read(parent_fds[0], fromParent, 100);
        fromParent[n] = 0;
        printf("Child: reading from parent pipe '%s'\n", fromParent);
        close(parent_fds[0]);

        // Concatinate to what was read in
        const char myText[14] = " (added this.)";
        strcat(fromParent, myText);

        write(child_fds[1], fromParent, strlen(fromParent));
        close(child_fds[1]);
        printf("Child: writing to pipe - '%s'\n", fromParent);
    } else {
        // read from child pipe
        int n = read(child_fds[0], fromChild, 100);
        fromChild[n] = 0;
        printf("Parent: reading from pipe - '%s'\n", fromChild);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### What is going wrong?

Comment: The order of your pipe operations are not correct. You need to `fork` first. Then do the respective parent and child `close` calls followed by the respective `read` and `write` calls.

Comment: When debugging, preferably write to `stderr`.  When you write to `stdout` (in particular; also for writing to `stderr`), ensure that you end messages with a newline.  Consider using `fflush(stdout);` to ensure the output is visible.  Include PID numbers in output — use `getpid()` in the printing call to make sure you don't get stale values across `fork()` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several problems, and your diagnostic messages were not guaranteed to appear.  Make sure you end your messages with newlines.

1. You only created one pipe because you used `&&` instead of `||`.
2. You closed the pipes 'for the parent' before you'd created the child (also noted by [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104813/using-two-pipes-to-communicate-between-parent-process-and-child-process#comment106303798_60104813)).

There are multiple other cleanups in the code below.  The code (still) does not ensure that the write-to-pipe operations succeed (they were failing before).  It does ensure that the strings read from the pipes are not longer than the buffers in which they are placed; it doesn't ensure there's enough space to append the extra information in the child.  The code shown waits for any child processes to complete before exiting.  The child executes the `wait()` call but it immediately fails (and the child doesn't print anything) and it exits.  The parent waits for the child to complete and reports on it doing so before exiting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // create two pipes:
    // - parent_fds used by parent to write to child
    // - child_fds used by child to write to parent
    int parent_fds[2], child_fds[2];

    // read:[0] - write:[1]
    if (pipe(parent_fds) != 0 || pipe(child_fds) != 0)  /* || not && */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipes failed!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // fork() child process
    int child = fork();

    if (child < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (child == 0)
    {
        printf("%d: I reached the child :)\n", (int)getpid());
        // close unwanted pipe ends by child
        close(child_fds[0]);
        close(parent_fds[1]);

        // read from parent pipe
        char fromParent[100];
        int n = read(parent_fds[0], fromParent, sizeof(fromParent) - 1);
        fromParent[n] = '\0';
        printf("%d: Child: read from parent pipe '%s'\n", (int)getpid(), fromParent);
        close(parent_fds[0]);

        // Append to what was read in
        strcat(fromParent, " (added this.)");

        write(child_fds[1], fromParent, strlen(fromParent));
        close(child_fds[1]);
        printf("%d: Child: writing to pipe - '%s'\n", (int)getpid(), fromParent);
    }
    else
    {
        // close unwanted pipe ends by parent
        close(parent_fds[0]);
        close(child_fds[1]);

        // write from terminal to parent pipe FOR child to read
        printf("%d: Parent: writing to pipe '%s'\n", (int)getpid(), argv[1]);
        write(parent_fds[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(parent_fds[1]);
        // read from child pipe
        char fromChild[100];
        int n = read(child_fds[0], fromChild, sizeof(fromChild) - 1);
        fromChild[n] = '\0';
        close(child_fds[0]);
        printf("%d: Parent: read from pipe - '%s'\n", (int)getpid(), fromChild);
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("%d: child PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sample output (source `pipe43.c`, program `pipe43`):

```
$ pipe43 'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!'
84543: Parent: writing to pipe 'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!'
84544: I reached the child :)
84544: Child: read from parent pipe 'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!'
84544: Child: writing to pipe - 'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition! (added this.)'
84543: Parent: read from pipe - 'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition! (added this.)'
84543: child PID 84544 exited with status 0x0000
$
```

Comment: I thought I had commented on this. But just incase it was deleted or something I wanted to say thank you. After reading through and testing it and altering the code, I understood how it worked. In addition I went to more office hours and the concept now makes much more sense to me and I was able to complete everything. Although turned in late, he appreciated I took the time to investigate and learn how it actually worked. I like higher end comp sci classes because they grasp the learning process.